# How to convert a pointer of type void(*)() to void*

Tags: c++

How to convert a pointer of type `void(*)()` to `void *`?

is any of the following operators can be used to do so?

- `const_cast`
- `static_cast`
- `dynamic_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`

Example: all of the following are compiled (*tried in Visual Studio 2017*), I wonder if they all have the same result after converting.

```
void operation(void(*callback)()) {

    void* test1 = callback;
    void* test2 = static_cast<void*>(callback);
    void* test3 = reinterpret_cast<void*>(callback);
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Is there an underlying reason for your question?

Comment: Portably, you can't.

Comment: @BrianCain Saw this question in an interview.

Comment: @Ali As for your example: [Not all of these conversions are permitted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff749de9ffc2aebb)!

Comment: @user0042 I can compile that code in VS2017. (also updated the question, thanks).

Comment: Weeeeelll, @Quentin, is that for sure the case?  Didn't mention anything about invoking the function pointer.

Comment: @BrianCain fair doubt. [8.2.10§8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8) explicitly makes it implementation-defined, with restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ISO standard C++, there is no implicit conversion from any function pointer type to any object pointer type.  So this line is ill-formed.

```
void* test1 = callback;
```

For the compiler to accept this without a diagnostic is a bug<sup>1</sup> (you do have warnings enabled, correct?)

`static_cast` between any object pointer type and a function pointer type (either direction) is prohibited in standard C++.  The controlling rule is found in 5.2.9:

> Otherwise, the `static_cast` shall perform one of the conversions listed below. No other conversion shall be performed explicitly using a `static_cast`.

Since none of the rules above or below discuss function pointer casts, this forbids the line

```
void* test2 = static_cast<void*>(callback);
```

However, this is not necessarily a separate compiler bug, because one of the rules does permit `static_cast` to be used to accomplish any implicit conversion.

The final line is the only correct one:

```
void* test3 = reinterpret_cast<void*>(callback);
```

The controlling rule is provided in the specification for `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10)

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

---

<sup>1</sup> When standard-compliant mode is enabled using `/Za`, the Microsoft C++ compilers do correctly reject the copy-initialization and `static_cast` attempts:

> source_file.cpp(8): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from `void (*)(void)` to `void *`
>
> source_file.cpp(8): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast
>   or function-style cast
>
> source_file.cpp(9): error C2440: `static_cast`:
>   cannot convert from `void (*)(void)` to `void *`
>
> source_file.cpp(9):
>   note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires
>   reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Answer (score 3):

In Standard C++, since C++11, it is *conditionally-supported*, which means that an implementation may or may not support it, and must document whether it is supported.

For implementations that do support this cast, the appropriate cast operator to use is `reinterpret_cast`. The details can be found in the C++14 standard [expr.reinterpret.cast]/8.

It's an error to try and convert a function pointer to an object pointer with no cast ([conv.ptr]), or with `static_cast` ([expr.static.cast]/5).  If your compiler permits this in standard mode and doesn't issue a diagnostic then the compiler is non-conforming.

Comment: `const_cast`'s could also be applied, but the example doesn't fit for that anyways.

Comment: @user0042 `const_cast` may only be used to add or remove cv-qualifiers

Comment: Sure! I mentioned the example isn't appropriate.

Comment: " Compilers may offer an extension which you would access with reinterpret_cast"  What does this mean?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I'm not sure how to proceed with your comment, but I have re-worded my answer

Comment: @user0042 the question is about how to cast `void(*)()` to `void *` , you seem to have misread it as "what do cast operators do". The question isn't "an example".

Comment: Note that this is guaranteed to be supported on POSIX platforms since this functionality is required by POSIX for support of the `dlsym` function.